# How to change CloudSQL global setting

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm testing apache airflow and I would like to make CloudSQL it's database but for it to work I need to change a global setting called 'explicit_defaults_for_timestamp' on my database.

I would like to know how I can make this change since I don't have SUPER user privilege on CloudSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Google Cloud SQL is fully managed by Google, you cannot perform actions that requires SUPER user privileges. There is a [list of supported flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags) that you can change without having SUPER user privileges. However, the flag that you are trying to import is not supported in that list, so, sadly you'll be unable to change that global setting.

Comment: is there a way to ask them to change this setting on my DB?

Comment: I'm afraid to say that this will no be possible at the moment. Sorry. However, there's a feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/79189571, there is no ETA, but you can stay tuned there.